# ScrollView doesn't show the upper part of XML in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, scrollview

My XML was working perfectly, it has a listview, set of textviews, imageviews and buttons. Then I added a scroll view to the entire layout. Listview stopped functioning and then I added a custom class in order t o make it work. Now everything is working as intended, but the issue is that the top part of the layout is not visible when the xml loads, I have to scroll up to see the top part of it.
My issue is same as this but still the provided solutions don't work: [ScrollView doesn't show top part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798401/scrollview-doesnt-show-top-part)
This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_default"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/navigation"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/app_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="#057afb"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_layout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/navigation_layout"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >



                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/app_icon"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_install"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/app_icon"
                    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_apps_install_button_selector" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/app_icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/app_icon"
                    android:text="desription goes here"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_desc_long"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/app_icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/app_icon"
                    android:text="desription goes here"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                    android:text="...More"
                    android:textColor="#057afb" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_layout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/navigation_layout1"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_desc"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/separator_app_details" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/information"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/information"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/version"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#929292" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_version"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                    android:text="@string/uploader"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#929292" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                    android:text="@string/updated"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#929292" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/information"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                    android:text="@string/size"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#929292" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                    android:text="@string/compatibility"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#929292" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_uploader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_version"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_updated"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_uploader"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_uploader"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_size"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_updated"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_compat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_size"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/information"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                    android:text="@string/txt_info"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="19sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_layout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/navigation_layout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/older_versions"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/old"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="19sp" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/older_versions"
                    android:divider="@null" >
                </ListView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/navigation_layout3"
            android:background="@drawable/separator_app_details" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the class that was written to make both scroll view and the list view function at the same time:

```
public class Utility {

    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

}
```

[image: wrong image]
[image: correct image]

Comment: Which part exactly is firstly visible when you open the `ScrollView` (paste some screenshots as well, just for information)? Thanks

Comment: Please see the edited question, Left image is the wrong one, right image should be the correct way!

Comment: Put this in the `OnCreate` method : `final ScrollView scrollview = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview));

scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
    }
});`

Comment: hey this worked!!!!, please post as an answer, I will accept, thanks a million!!

Comment: Having had a look at some code of mine for comparison, could you please try adding a layout to your XML that holds the `ScrollView`? I usually define a `LinearLayout` to hold my `ScrollView`s. I think the lack of a container might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this in the `OnCreate()` method:

```
final ScrollView scrollview = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview)); scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
  }
});
```

The code above provides you with a way to force the scroll of the `ScrollView` at the upper position. This behavior can be caused even by a `weight` attribute in a some layouts etc. The "debugging" of this will take more time that to apply the solution above and there isn't a guarantee that you can know each time which disturbs your initial scroll position.

Comment: Could you please comment on your solution and why it solves the problem? I can of course see that you force focus but shouldn't the user be able to scroll up if he wants to anyway? Is it the omission of the declaration of the `ScrollView` that causes the problem?

Comment: I will paste some info in the Answer, you're right. But what do you mean by "shouldn't the user be able to scroll up if he wants to anyway" and "the omission of the declaration of the ScrollView" - which declaration are you talking about?

Comment: Before applying the solution that you gave me, page loaded without the upper part, which is not the usual way. But with your solution, the view is now acting normal, upper part is being loaded first then the user can gradually scroll down, also he can come up when he reached the end.

Comment: I meant that since you are forcing the focus, the content of the `ScrollView` must exist. Since it is a scrollable view, why can't the user simply scroll up to see it. The OP specified it is not visible which, to me, reads different to the view just having a wrong focus to start with. I was just fishing to see what the problem is with my comment about the declaration. While you provided a solution, I still cannot see where the problem could have been!

Comment: I think it's related to the `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` and `android:layout_weight="1" ` of the `RelativeLayout`s inside the `LinearLayouts`, which get all centered around the middle ones. This however is a hypothesis.

Comment: The layout in question resides inside the `ScrollView`so this shouldn't be the issue!

Comment: What I think has happened is whenthe `ScrollView` got created it searched for a focus point to start at and the fact that th first `LinearLayout` does not have `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` it searches for the next most appropriate candidate to throw the focus on. In this case it's the last `TextView` and I think that the `ScrollView` just starts scrolled to bottom, which can be explained with that (I didn't actually see that it starts like that, but now I think it started scrolled to the bottom).

Comment: I had a similar issue and indeed, putting `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in the child element of the `ScrollView` solved the issue. (Which imo is a clear solution.)